# How to read from console in netbeans 7.0

Tags: java, netbeans-7

Here is my sample program:

```
// writing into a file

package file;
import java.io.*;

public class Writeintofile {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try
        {
        FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/Pavan/Desktop/Myjava/File/bin/city.txt");
        int i;
        while((i=System.in.read())!=-1)
        {
            fos.write(i);
        }

        // TODO code application logic here
    }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
}
}
```

Am not able to enter data on the console. What changes do i need to make so that Netbeans can read the data from the console?

But everything is working fine if the program is executed from the windows command prompt.

Comment: Define 'not able'. Any problem entering data is an input problem, not a FileOutputStream problem. It seems to me that your real difficulty is locating where to type in NetBeans.

Comment: got it. net beans donot show a focus to enter a data on the console. I just entered on the console and everything's working fine now.

Answer (score -1):

Your FileOutputStream is not closed correctly, it may have the reason that you think it is not reading from console and writing to file.

```
FileOutputStream fos=null;//initialize Fileoutputstream.


    finally
    {
      fos.close();
    }
```

Comment: It would explain why he is isn't writing to the file, if FileOutputStream was buffered, which it isn't, but it doesn't explain why he isn't reading from the console. You're quite right to say he should close the file, but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: i have shown poster it may be cause that, he/she didnt close the fos ,if it is somehow poster not able to write to file and he/she thinks that it can be becs cannot read from console.

Comment: You have specifically stated that this 'may have the reason why it is not reading from console'. It's wrong.

Comment: @EJP Edited , missed a word. Thanks.